# Placing my website in progress online dangerous for future google seo

Tags: seo, facebook-social-plugins, staging

I'm building a website for a company, I build this website offline so google won't index it, with the reason that google don't see the codes yet and thinks at the official launch that we copied the text/codes from an other website.

Sadly I encounterd a problem. I need to implant the facebook social plugin, sadly does this plugin only work when the site is online. But as I said putting it online can be dangerous for future Google SEO.

Is there an other option where I can see the facebook plugin but it is not online yet or is it okay for me to just place it online already on (for example) www.example.com and later put the released product on (for example) www.released.com.

Any toughts on this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you place the website online in a folder that is blocked for Googlebot via robots.txt?

That way you can test all the online elements work and not have to worry about users and search engines finding it and listing it.

An alternative could be to use the .htaccess file to limit access only to your IP address - that way, you'd be the only one to see the site live.

Comment: making a document called robot.txt in your main directory and putting : "User-agent: *
Disallow: / " in it work to not let it seen by google?

Comment: Yes, that will work as well. The advantage of putting it in a directory rather than the root folder is that if visitors or other search bots also go to the top level domain, they wouldn't be able to see the website before it's ready to go live, unless they know the name of the specific directory.